# Custom Field Validation in WFFM (MVC)

Tags: wffm, validation

In our website, we have the requirement to validate some WFFM Form field's based on third-party system data. We want to display the error message near to field (like required field validation).

Is there any way to write custom WFFM field validation that will check the data on server side.

Version - Sitecore WFFM 8.1

Comment: yes, it is. Follow this article https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/82/working_with_actions_and_validations/validations/walkthrough_create_and_assign_a_custom_fieldtype_validator

Comment: I think The example link you given is for ASP.Net Form's validation.

Comment: no, it is not. It describes how to create your own custom field validator. When you have this validator you should be able to add this validator to your WFFM form(s).

Comment: If we create custom filed and apply custom Field validation Attribute then it is working . But as per document Note
'The MVC implementation of WFFM does not use the validation item structure
/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Validation for field validation.' <br/> I was looking for solution , that will add a independent validation attribute and it can be plugged in any filed . like it was happening in WEB Forms